# MongoDB Query returning false results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have streamlined this question for simplicity.  Value is passed to the function, and if there is no document with {field1: value}, create that document; otherwise, call another function.  However, this query will always find a document, or perhaps fires whatever_function() regardless.  Why can I not get (!doc) to be true?  This database is operative and queries/updates appropriately except for this issue.

```
    db.doc.find({field1: value}, function(err, doc) {
        if (!doc) {
            db.doc.save({field1: value});
        }
        else {
            whatever_function();            
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you only intrested in finding one document, use `findOne`, since `find` returns cursor and not array of docs (other way: `db.doc.find(selector).toArray(callback)` and test array's length). Also, you should take a look at `findAndModify` with `upsert` option.

Comment: Thanks el migranto, findOne method is exactly what I needed!  Appreciate the array method as well. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Find returns a cursor to the selected documents. Then, you should check that doc length is 0.